# Flask not updating python code dynamically

Tags: python, flask

I am running a web application that return hello world to a web browser using python. The code is as follows:

1. Code:

   ```
    from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")

    def index():
        return "Hello World!"
   ```
2. after this i am using the command flask run to run the application.py file
3. Which is working fine on browser. but now if i reset the code again on application.py file to return "Hello world! hello again" and reload the website port the results are not affected in the browser
   It still returns "Hello World!"

Comment: Can you check the terminal? you might found the exceptions

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact command you use in step 2 and the full output on the command line after step 3.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't set the FLASK_ENV environment.

Comment: `flask app` not get auto updated itself when changes are made. You have to stop the server by pressing `Ctrl + C` in terminal first and then you have to retype `flask run` to start the server then the site will run with updated version. that's how changes take place in flask.

Comment: @FareedKhan not exactly true since if the app was run in a development environment (and not behind a webserver), then any changes to the code will trigger an update; however, not all changes are registered and there tends to be a race condition if you save often (as I often do) which then I'd have to restart the server.

Comment: browser may keep old page in cache and gives you old version. You can run the same url with some random `value` after `?` and browser will think you ask for different page - `http://127.0.0.0/?value`. OR you can find in browser option to turn off cache - in `Firefox` you can find it even in `DevTools` - in tab `Network`

Comment: BTW: if I'm not wrong using `F5` or `Ctrl+R` you reload page and browser may get it from cache but `Ctrl+F5` or `Ctrl + Shift + R` should reload without using cache.

Answer (score 2):

set this in terminal

> export FLASK_ENV=development

or if this not work then try to open URL in other browser

Answer (score 1):

1. check the log in terminal to see whether it get re-loaded after your update.
2. if not, activate the debug mode in flask: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#debug-mode

```
export FLASK_DEBUG=1  //Linux or Mac:
set FLASK_DEBUG=1    //windows
```

3. also try in Incognito Windows of Browser (which is cache-free)